# Convert bits/ms to mm/s

Tags: correlation

I developed a tool to communicate via COM ports, yet i'm facing a problem.

My "remote tool" has a parameter in bits/ms , but my machine only works in mm/s ( it's a laser system and i can't change that).

I've tried in practice and `225 bits/ms` is something like `400mm/s` ..
Help pls?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your remote tool has a scale factor that one bit/ms of output corresponds to some number of mm/s.  You might be able to find the value in the documentation.  Otherwise, taking the value you give, you get $1$ bit/ms = $\frac {400}{225}$ mm/s $=\frac {16}9$ mm/s $\approx 1.78$ mm/s

Comment: i just found that it is 600counts/mm

Comment: The other conversion you need is $1$ sec $=1000$ msec and you are there.

Comment: yep it's done. 1mm/sec = 0.6bits/ms. right?

Comment: Yes, I have the inverse of that above and corrected a typo.  Your measurement was close.